# Accessing class function inside a function in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building in application in Angular 2 and am still having some trouble understanding the this scope of TypeScript.

I have TypeScript class called SharedService, when the function *handleError* receives a 401 status, I want it to call *logout()*. This is also a function in the class.

A read that, in order to use functions in combination with *this* I should use the arrow function definition as I did in my example below, somehow this still returns:

> TypeError: this.logout is not a function(…)

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

```
export class SharedService {

    logout = () => {
      console.log('Logout.');
    }

    //This method catches any errors that might arise upon http requests
    handleError(error: any) {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.logout(); <----------------------------- This returns the error
        }
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    }
}
```

The error occurs when this.logout() is called!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.bind(this)`

```
logout() {
  ...
  return this._http.delete(url, options)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

or arrow functions

```
logout() {
  ...
  return this._http.delete(url, options)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
```

The disadvantage in this case is that the parameters need to be repeated with `=>` while this is not necessary with `.bind(this)`.
When the callback is defined inline `() =>` is usually more convenient.

Comment: The error occurs when I call this.logout(), I edited my example.

Comment: That's what I understood but I assume that's caused by the way you call `handleError`. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Some useful info on the why the arrow function (lambda, rocket, whatever) behaves how it does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
Namely at the start "does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's because typescript make `logout` function to SharedService function.

like this:

```
  function SharedService() {
            var _this = this;
            this.logout = function () {
                console.log('Logout.');
                var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
                var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
                var url = API_URL + 'users/sign_out.json';
                return _this._http.delete(url, options)
                    .map(function (res) { return res; })
                    .catch(_this.handleError);
            };
        }
```

and `handleError` it's make to the prototype:

```
  //This method catches any errors that might arise upon http requests
        SharedService.prototype.handleError = function (error) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this.logout();
            }
            var errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                error.status ? error.status + " - " + error.statusText : 'Server error';
            console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        };
```

and `this` change to another scope.

so you should need to use:
`.catch(() => this.handleError);`